# Clear understanding of two concepts

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I have been studying about oscillation, where I get to know about its two types (i.e)

1. Harmonic motion
2. Non Harmonic Motion

While studying about harmonic motion,I came to know that force is directly proportional to the negative of displacement

Now take an example of pendulum
let,

- M be the mean position
- L be the "to" position
- N be the "fro" position

When we displace pendulum with x towards "to" then the restoring force will act towards mean position and eventually covering same x distance from mean position in "fro"

For me, Harmonic motion is a motion covering equal distance from mean position towards to as well as fro position and repeating itself regularly

For me,non harmonic motion is something which doesn't cover equal distance from mean position [(i.e) x distance from to and x' distance from fro position] and gradually repeating itself

I only want to know if my way of understanding the two concepts is correct or wrong somewhere? If I did any type of mistake in understanding please rectify

Comment: No,  it is not. Pendulum is an example of non-harmonic motion with the equilibrium position in the middle.

Comment: Pendulum is considered having SHM at small values of angle displaced from mean position for simplicity.

Comment: Yes,  for small oscillations it can be approximated by SHO. And so can be any system in small oscillation regime.  But limiting yourself to this special case you never have non harmonic motion and then you never touch the object of this question.